# Windows phone notification that stays till user checks

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, notifications, push-notification

I am new to windows phone app dev. I want to know if there is any way to have a notification alive till the user checks it. I found that "toast notification" expires in 10 seconds irrespective of user checks it or not. And there is no way of finding out if a tile notification arrived or not. Is there any workaround? I want to have notifications that are similar to Android notifications which stay till user checks them.

Answer (score 1):

Persistent on-screen notifications on Windows Phone are not possible, by intentional design. It's interesting to see how many users on Android disliked persistent notifications when applications started to interrupt and then disrupt the current foreground application experience.

The design philosophy is that they distract from the user experience and could be easily abused by applications.

The general Microsoft recommendation for the platform would be to use a combination of a notification, Live Tile ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), and in application UI update.

In Android 4.3, the behavior was changed to highlight applications that were constantly running ([interesting reference](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/29/android-engineer-explains-why-some-apps-suddenly-have-persistent-notifications-after-you-upgrade-to-android-4-3/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use "MessageBox.Show(String)".

Refer below for:

1. [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms598674%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
2. [Example 1](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/delivering-message-using)
3. [Example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271596/Customizing-MessageBox-on-Windows-Phone-7)

Comment: How is this equivalent to a Notification?

Comment: his requirement "I want to know if there is any way to have a notification alive till the user checks it". So message box will stay till user checks it.

Comment: Unless the app is in the foreground, how would  message box help?

Comment: Yes, what you say is true. Well I too don't know any workaround. Perhaps you or others can help to solve it.